# how to create a loadable kernel module .ko and make it part of a default linux image

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to build a linux image using pengutronix. how to create a loadable kernel module .ko and make it part of a default linux image.

I have one of the kernel module as "<m>" there is no <*>(builtin) option for it .but i want to module to be part of the linux image, Ex) The .ko to be inside the /lib/modules folder.

Comment: By "using pengutronix", do you mean "using PTXdist"?

Comment: In PTXdist, using the `menuconfig platform` (or `platformconfig`) subcommand, there is a configuration option to install kernel modules. `[*] Linux kernel --->` `[*]   build kernel-modules` `[*]     Install modules into /lib/modules`.

Comment: modules are ko files in /lib/modules. Built-in code is linked into the vmlinux image. It is not clear what you want.